# Adding repeat logic to multiple classes in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have some classes, let's call them: Student, Subject and Teacher.

I want all of these classes to share this "group" logic:

```
export class ObjectGroup {
    protected group: string;

    setGroup(group: string) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    getGroup(): string {
        return this.group;
    }
}
```

Do I really need to add this logic into each class? This isn't a case in which extending my classes would make sense.

Comment: Create a reusable class for sharing the common functionality

Comment: @NinjaJami As in add an ObjectGroup instantiation as a property of my classes? Or are you describing something else? I did think of this, but I really want the functionality to be directly associated to the class like, Student.getGroup(), not, Student.group.getGroup()

Comment: @NinjaJami Since `group` is a common trait of your classes I would put the group attribute in an abstract class.
Alternatively you can utilise the [mixins pattern](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html), but that's a bit overkill IMO

Answer (score 0):

Use an abstract class for your classes' common traits:

```
abstract class Group {
   private _group: string = '';
   get group(): string { return this._group; }
   set group(value: string) { this._group = value; }
}

class Student extends Group {} 
const student = new Student();
student.group = "a group";
console.log(student.group); //"a group"
```